# PostgreSQL floating point arithmetic and types

Tags: database, postgresql, floating-point

I have a Postgres-driven application which rounds quantities to the next (not nearest) 4th decimal place. So, 0.00341 becomes 0.0035.

In implementing it, I came upon a situation where 0.0012 *even* is being rounded up to 0.0013, even though it shouldn't; it's 0.0012 even. In fact, even `ceil()` agrees, at first glance:

```
postgres=> SELECT ceil(((0.0012) * 10000)) / 10000;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.00120000000000000000
(1 row)
```

We know that there is no arbitrary precision introduced:

```
postgres=> SELECT (ceil(((0.0012) * 10000)) / 10000) = 0.0012;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Yet, when the figure 0.0012 is arrived at by way of a *computation*, the situation changes:

```
postgres=> SELECT (12::double precision / 60) * 0.006;
 ?column? 
----------
   0.0012
(1 row)

postgres=> SELECT ((12::double precision / 60) * 0.006) = 0.0012;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

It would appear that the computed 0.0012 is greater than actual 0.0012:

```
postgres=> SELECT ((12::double precision / 60) * 0.006) > 0.0012;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Predictably, this leads the rounding mechanism to round 0.0012 "up" to 0.0013, which is obviously wrong if the expression evaluates to 0.0012 even:

```
postgres=> SELECT ceil(((12::double precision / 60) * 0.006) * 10000) / 10000;
 ?column? 
----------
   0.0013
(1 row)
```

So, clearly I'm missing something here about how the expression is evaluated and/or how the data types involved are cast. There's additional precision introduced that shouldn't be there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's in no way specific to Postgres. I get the same result in a number of programming languages, so, obviously I am missing something about types and precision.

Comment: PostgreSQL (and any others) does not use its own arithmetic but uses CPU/OS instead. There are a lot of info about [limitations of floating points arithmetic usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Specify the appropriate precision/scale to get the properly results. For example, `SELECT ((12::numeric(16,8) / 60) * 0.006) = 0.0012;` returns `t`

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the error of my ways. This is a job for the `numeric` type in PostgreSQL, which is an arbitrary-precision type intended precisely to provide exact calculation.

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html:

> 8.1.2. Arbitrary Precision Numbers
>
> The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits
>   and perform calculations exactly. It is especially recommended for
>   storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is
>   required. However, arithmetic on numeric values is very slow compared
>   to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the
>   next section.